# Why my application is started automatically after install

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS programming.

Currently working on an Enterprise Application which is downloaded from the web and suppose to be activated with a URL schema.

When the download and install process is completed the application is started **automatically** by iOS without the URL schema and without the user activating the application.
At this stage the application is asking the user to activate it with a schema but this Alert is not being displayed, nighter the application main view.
Double click the home button display the splash screen of my application together with other running apps.

When the user press the registration link:

`applicationWillEnterForeground` is being called.
   `openURL` is being called.
   `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is **NOT** being called.

The application display the register with link (the alert that was not displayed earlier) and exit.

My questions:

1. Why my application is starting automatically? 
   [edit] Forgot to mention that this is a VOIP application so iOS gives us a chance to set up the connection.
2. How come the AlertView is not being displayed?
3. Is there a way to prevent it?
4. If there is no way to prevent it, is there a way to detect this state?

I'm using XCode 5 and iOS7 on iPhone 4 (but saw this behaviour on other devices as well).

Thanks, 
Yaron

Comment: is `openURL` called when the app is launched "automatically" ?

Comment: No, only during the second launch (via the link)